# Enqueue AWS Script

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, amazon, web-services

I am working on the integration of an Amazon Webstore (Amazon Checkout) on a WordPress site using Amazon Documentation [here](http://amazonpayments.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/Shopping_Cart_Guide.pdf). Has been a while since I worked with enqueueing external JScripts. I need to load two scripts from Amazon. I added some code to functions.php, but I seem to have made a mistake and I keep on getting errors such as:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(jQuery(document).find("#globalParameters"))').
```

On merchant_cart.js:5

Here is the code:

```
    function img_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'aws-cba', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/cba/js/common/cba_shared.js',  array( 'jquery' ));

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aws-cba' );
    //second script
        wp_register_script( 'aws-merchant-cart', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/cba/js/shoppingcart/merchant_cart.js',  array( 'jquery' ));

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aws-merchant-cart' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'img_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

What coding mistake am I making here? is the enqueueing of these two external scripts in need of jQuery OK?

**Update**

Loading scripts in footer makes things better, but when I added the button to load the cart I still got the same error. Current script is now:

```
/Enqueue AWS Scripts

function img_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the First Script:
    wp_register_script( 'aws-cba', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/cba/js/common/cba_shared.js',  array( 'jquery' ),'version', true );

    // Enqueue it:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aws-cba' );
    //Register Second Script
        wp_register_script( 'aws-merchant-cart', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/cba/js/shoppingcart/merchant_cart.js',  array( 'jquery' ), 'version', true);

    // Enqueue this one too:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aws-merchant-cart' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'img_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

**Update II**

Firebug described the error as follows:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/cba/js/shoppingcart/merchant_cart.js?ver=version
Line 5
```

Seems like a jQuery conflict..

Comment: Check page source code for jQuery is loaded. AWS scripts too.

Comment: They are loaded. Loading them in the footer now. But as soon as I added the HTML to load the link allowing to view the cart I have same earlier mentioned JScript error.

Comment: @Max Yudin Adding `<script ="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  </script>` to the header only causes another error saying that jQuery cannot be found as a variable.

Comment: Well, baffled here at the moment. Taking a break now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to save `jQuery.noConflict();` as `jquery-no-conflict.js`. Then enqueue everything with proper dependencies:

```
<?php
function img_scripts_with_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'jquery-no-conflict',
        'path/to/jquery-no-conflict.js',
        array(
            'jquery'
        ),
        'version',
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'aws-cba',
        'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/cba/js/common/cba_shared.js',
        array(
            'jquery-no-conflict'
        ),
        'version',
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'aws-merchant-cart',
        'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/cba/js/shoppingcart/merchant_cart.js',
        array(
            'jquery-no-conflict'
        ),
        'version',
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'img_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

Comment: Worked like a charm with the noconflict script. Next step is HTML integration of cart and so on. Thanks!